# Batch Scripting. Spliting a special string(<=>) and extracting it. (XML to EXCEL)How?

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, scripting

There is a xml file where I want to extract it into excel file using batch scripting.

Text:

```
<TableCell width="20" class="normal">10.0.0.1</TableCell>
    <Paragraph>5900/tcp</Paragraph></TableCell>
<TableCell width="20" class="normal">10.0.0.1</TableCell>
    <Paragraph>139/tcp</Paragraph></TableCell>
<TableCell width="20" class="normal">10.0.0.2</TableCell>
    <Paragraph>445/tcp</Paragraph></TableCell>
<TableCell width="20" class="normal">10.0.0.3</TableCell>
    <Paragraph>139/tcp</Paragraph></TableCell>
<TableCell width="20" class="normal">10.0.0.3</TableCell>
    <Paragraph>445/tcp</Paragraph></TableCell>
<TableCell width="20" class="normal">10.0.0.2</TableCell>
    <Paragraph>443/tcp</Paragraph></TableCell>
<TableCell width="20" class="normal">10.0.0.3</TableCell>
    <Paragraph>1311/tcp</Paragraph></TableCell>
<TableCell width="20" class="normal">10.0.0.1</TableCell>
    <Paragraph>1443/tcp</Paragraph></TableCell>
<TableCell width="20" class="normal">10.0.0.4</TableCell>
    <Paragraph>443/tcp</Paragraph></TableCell>
```

Code that I have come out so far, still stuck at the splitting part, because there is an error

Code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET LOCAL

SET "file=C:\Users\Intern3\Downloads\Nmap\Nex\1.txt"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=^>" %%a IN ("%file%") DO (
echo %%a %%b
CALL :process %%a %%b)

GOTO :eof

:process
echo %*
pause
ECHO %*|FIND "class" > NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ip

GOTO :eof

:ip
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=^=" %%b IN (%*) DO (
pause
ECHO %%b, %%c, %%d)

GOTO :eof
```

For now there are echo in the code because I wanted to see where the mistake is.

The error only appear when it is reading the ip address. But for the port everything is find.

Error:

```
The system cannot find the file width
```

The output is suppose to be like this

Example Output:

```
10.0.0.1
5900/tcp
139/tcp
1443/tcp

10.0.0.2
445/tcp
443/tcp

10.0.0.3
139/tcp
1311/tcp
445/tcp

10.0.0.4
443/tcp
```

Supposed output. But i am still stuck at splitting the ip address.
Please help. Thank you

Comment: *I'm using absolutely the wrong tool for the job, and I have problems. Please help!* Why are you trying to do this in a batch file? Excel will directly import XML, and you can work with it much more easily using VBA string functions and looping through cells than you'll ever be able to with a batch file. Stop trying to do surgery using a hammer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q43533312.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" GOTO maketemp
COPY NUL "%tempfile%a" >nul

(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-7delims=<=> " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (

 IF /i "%%a%%g"=="Tablecell/Tablecell" SET ip=%%f
 IF /i "%%a%%c"=="Paragraph/Paragraph" CALL :record %%b

)
)>"%tempfile%a"

SET "ip="

(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('sort "%tempfile%a"') DO CALL :report %%a
)>"%outfile%"
DEL "%tempfile%a"
GOTO :EOF

:record

FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=." %%p IN ("%ip%") DO (
 SET /a ip1=1000+%%p
 SET /a ip2=1000+%%q
 SET /a ip3=1000+%%r
 SET /a ip4=1000+%%s
)
FOR /f "tokens=1-2delims=/" %%p IN ("%1") DO (
 SET /a port1=1000000+%%p
 SET /a port2=%%q
)

ECHO %ip1%%ip2%%ip3%%ip4% %port1%%port2% %ip% %1

GOTO :eof

:report
IF "%ip%"=="%3" GOTO dataline
IF DEFINED ip ECHO.
SET "ip=%3"
ECHO %ip%

:dataline
ECHO %4
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q43533312.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Read the file and tokenise on the characters nominated.

For the lines where the first and seventh tokens are the `tablecell` pair, set `ip` to the sixth token. For those with the first and third being the other pair, call the `:record` routine passing the text in the second token.

The `:record` routine tokenises `ip` using `.`, and adds 1000 to each element. Since each element must be 0..255, this provides a set of numbers which are 1000..1255, so they are all the same length.

Similarly, split the string in the first argument on `/`, and add a large number to the first element so that any value will produce a constant-length string.

Output the calculated elements along with the raw source data by `echo`ing. The fact that the controlling `for` in the mainline is enclosed in parentheses and redirected will send the data to the tempfile.

Finally, sort the tempfile and call `:report` with the content of each line. A change of `ip` in argument 3 means the IP needs to be output on its own  line; if it's the first one, `ip` won't be set (it's cleared before the `for/f` invoking the `sort`) means don't produce a new line as the first line.

Then show the port data in the fourth argument.